# How to fetch data in ajax from different fields when button is click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Description:** 
I want that when user click on button which is inside the while loop then the value of this button and input field value(both value) fetch by ajax and send it to php.
If there is something wrong in my code then correct it OR tell ma some method to do it.

```
<?php

    echo '<form id ="aa" method="post">';
    echo '<input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" />';
    echo '</form>';

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_1)) {
        $pin=$row['board_name'];
        $name=$row['board_name'];

        echo'<div>';
        echo $row['board_name'];
        echo '<button  type="submit" form="aa" class="a" name="aabb" value='.$name.'>Save</button>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".a").click(function(evt){     
            evt.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'pin_insert.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $(".text").html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why did you write the html code in php echo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jQuery so forgive any mistooks but perhaps the following as the `submit` buttons are outside the form even if they submitted a value it would not be included in the formdata so it needs to be appended to the data that is sent.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".a").click(function(evt){     
            evt.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById('aa') );

                /* Add the value from the button */
                formData.append( 'aabb', evt.target.value );

            $.ajax({
                url: 'pin_insert.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $(".text").html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

input field and button values are the same so i did it this way

```
 <?php

        echo '<form id ="aa" method="post">';
        echo '<input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" />';
        echo '</form>';

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_1)) {


            echo'<div>';
            echo $row['board_name'];
            echo '<button  type="button" form="aa" class="a" name="aabb" value='.$row['board_name'].' onclick="abc(this.value)">Save</button>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>

    <script>
    function abc(boardname){
               var inputvalue= $("#csv").val();

                var boardname= boardname;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'pin_insert.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                   data: {'boardname': boardname , 'inputvalue': inputvalue},
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $(".text").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }

    </script>
```

you can get the value from the pin_insert.php page $_POST['boardname'] $_POST['inputvalue']

Comment: No,input field and value of button is not same.User can input any file

Comment: so you want the value of the file and the button value right?